# Is there a pure Javascript way to apply one function to multiple element's events?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to bind a single function to multiple events using pure Javascript.

In jQuery I would use:

```
$('.className').click(function(e){ //do stuff });
```

So using pure JS I tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className').onclick = function(e){ //do stuff };
```

Which doesn't work, because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, not a DOM object.

I can loop through the array, but this seems overly verbose and like it shouldn't be necessary:

```
var topBars = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
for(var i = 0; i < topBars.length; i++){
    topBars[i].onclick = function(e){ //do stuff };
}
```

Is there a standard way to accomplish this with pure Javascript?

Comment: jQuery does the same looping .... only it does it under the hood

Comment: This is exactly the way jQuery does it. However you can use `Array.map.call()`. But it's not really slower/faster.

Comment: It could be `$(document).on('click', '.className', ...)` that literally attaches only a single handler. The same could be done in pure JS (using event bubbling)

Comment: You can use event delegation on the closest parent.

Comment: You could also extend the prototype of the `NodeList`, or `HTMLCollection’, but there would still be looping taking place, otherwise (as noted already) there's delegation.

Comment: @zerkms, is that not in jQuery ? which would be exactly what the question is saying not to use ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add the event handler to the parent element, and then determine whether one of the children elements with the desired classname is clicked:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if ((' ' + e.target.className + ' ').indexOf(' item ') !== -1) {
        // add logic here
        console.log(e.target);
    }
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kndkd2qL/)

or...

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.querySelectorAll('.item'), function (el) {
        if (el === e.target) {
            // add logic here
            console.log(e.target);
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9bmhorhr/)

---

The above snippets will only work when you are clicking on the element with the specified class. In other words, it won't work if you click on that given element's child. To work around that, you could use the following:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target; // Clicked element
    while (target && target.parentNode !== parent) {
        target = target.parentNode; // If the clicked element isn't a direct child
        if (!target) { return; } // If element doesn't exist
    }
    if ((' ' + target.className + ' ').indexOf(' item ') !== -1){
        // add logic here
        console.log(target);
    }
});
```

[**Alternative Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/56jz5chm/)

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

parent.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target; // Clicked element
    while (target && target.parentNode !== parent) {
        target = target.parentNode; // If the clicked element isn't a direct child
        if (!target) { return; } // If element doesn't exist
    }
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.querySelectorAll('.item'), function (el) {
        if (el === target) {
            // add logic here
            console.log(target);
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynzhvof7/)

Comment: `e.target.className.indexOf('item') === 0` should be `e.target.className.indexOf('item') !== -1` I think.

Comment: @JoshCrozier, I think it's getting awfully complicated in the second example. It's correct and still requires only one event handler. So I still like it :-)

Comment: Although I think looping is better (and less verbose) for my current needs, I'm going to select this answer as it appears to document the best alternate to looping.

Comment: Using *indexOf* will match any string in the className, e.g. 'items', 'lotsOfitems', etc. Consider `' ' + target.className + ' ').indexOf(' item ')` to match per the rules for matching class values.

Comment: @RobG Updated. Thanks Rob, appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 1):

As a hack, where the DOM is implemented using a prototype inheritance model (most browsers but not all), you can add an iterator to the NodeList constructor:

```
if (NodeList && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, callback, thisArg)
  }
}
```

Then:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', someFn, false);
})
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', someFn, false);
})
```

Of course you shouldn't do this in production on the web ([*don't mess with host objects*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) and all that), but wouldn't it be nice if it was OK? Or iterators were added to DOM lists and collections?

Comment: 1+ Nice one, I didn't realize that was possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.className');
var values = Array.prototype.map.call(elems, function(obj) {
    return obj.onclick = function(e){ //do stuff };
});
```

This (adapted example from MDN) is how you could do it without a traditional loop.

Comment: 1. It's not better than OP's code 2. It actually is worse

Comment: @zerkms. It's not better. I said that in my comment. But could you explain why it's worse? This example can be found on MDN (that in itself doesn't make it a good example). Please enlighten me.

Comment: `[class="classname"]` --- this selector is not identical to the selector in the question. And another personal thing: `[].map.call` --- I prefer to not create objects when not necessary: `Array.prototype.map.call` would do.

Comment: The issue was not in the case. It's a strict comparison. It will not match `class="foo className"`

Comment: With `[class*="className"]` it will match `class="fooclassName"` which it shouldn't. 4th attempt?

Comment: @zerkms The next time please point that out. Criticism should be constructive. I Would appreciate that.

Comment: We're haven't done yet - it's still wrong! :-) PS: sorry for not pointing it out, I thought it's obvious for "CSS (advanced)" & "Javascript (advanced)" :-)

Comment: @zerkms. While the last is certainly true. Using querySelector and selectors are a tat new to me. However I just wrote it and indeed there were some teething problems.

Comment: Well, at the moment it is broken :-( PS: it's not about `querySelector` being new, it's about knowing how selectors in `CSS` work (here we don't have any `querySelectorAll` specifics at all)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68613/discussion-between-mouser-and-zerkms).